# How can I trace through a JVM program given only the class files?

Tags: java

Is there a way to trace through a program given only the class files (not the debug version of the class files)?

Comment: I'm currently working on a project to do this.  You pretty much have to write your own JVM. :-)

Comment: Have you got a link to your project?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess that's possible. I just made a simple Fibonacci code, compiled it using "-g:none" (so no debugging info generated), then trace using [this](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jpda/trace.html).

You can see the invocation tree there.